# Iterate a grid of views SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'd like to take an array of variable length and return a grid of views with 3 columns and variable row lengths. The view should update it's content based off of the array value.

The following code will present a CardPicView for each card, with the title of "A"... "I" in a scroll view.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    let cards = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(cards.identified(by: \.self)) { card in
                    CardPicView(cardTitle: card)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to take this scrollview and divide it into 3 columns, essentially.

I have figured out that the below code can create a grid of the right size by using:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    let cards = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(0..<cards.count/3) { row in // create number of rows
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<3) { column in // create 3 columns
                        Text(self.cards[row])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this gives me a 3x4 grid with just (AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD)

Changing this to:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    let cards = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(0..<cards.count/3) { row in // create number of rows
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<3) { column in // create 3 columns
                        Text(self.cards[column])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gives me a 3x4 grid with just (ABC/ABC/ABC/ABC).

I somehow need to iterate over row and column using two indices, but not sure how to do this in swift.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there's anything specific in SwiftUI that prevents this. I think this is what you're trying to accomplish?

```
struct ContentView : View {
    let cards = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(0..<cards.count/3) { row in // create number of rows
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<3) { column in // create 3 columns
                        Text(self.cards[row * 3 + column])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well for the text grid. Thanks for the stepping stone! Small modification to use CardPicView(cardTitle: self.cards[row*3 + column]) worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: I find this throws an error: "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" Not sure how to do so.

Comment: @dot3 Likely, "row * 3 + column" operation is taking too long.  You may want to try creating the Text() view in a view builder function that returns the Text() within the loop.  e.g.  
func makeView(row: Int, column: Int) -> Text { 
    let row * 3 + column
    return Text(self.cards[row * 3 + column])
}

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it using Swift generics.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Grid<Content: View>: View {

    let rows: Int
    let columns: Int
    let content: (Int, Int) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(0..<rows) { row in
                Divider()
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30) {
                    ForEach(0..<self.columns) { (column) in
                        self.content(row, column)
                        .padding()
                    }
                    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.yellow, Color.green]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .shadow(radius: 3)
                }
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
}

struct CardPicView: View {
    @State var displayText: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
            Image(systemName: "\(displayText).circle.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text(displayText)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }
        .font(.title) // sets equal hight both for image and text
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var cards = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "w", "l", "m", "n", "ww"]
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    private var numberOfcolumns: Int {
        (horizontalSizeClass == .compact) ? 2 : 4
    }
    // need to ensure number of rows is rounded up to the next whole integer
    private var numberOfrows: Int {
        Int(ceil(Double(cards.count)/Double(numberOfcolumns)))
    }
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Grid(rows: numberOfrows, columns: numberOfcolumns) { (r, c) in
                CardPicView(displayText: self.cards[guarded: r*self.numberOfcolumns + c] ?? "_")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .background(Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.6, blue: 0.95))
    }
}

// subscript for safe access
extension Array {
   subscript(guarded idx: Int) -> Element? {
        guard (startIndex..<endIndex).contains(idx) else { return nil }
        return self[idx]
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
            .environment((\.horizontalSizeClass), .compact)
            ContentView()
             .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(stringLiteral: "iPad8,5"))
             .environment((\.horizontalSizeClass), .regular)
        }
    }
}
```

The result looks so:
[image: .compact and .regular layouts in one preview]

Comment: Its a lot going on in that code, nice use of generics though .

Answer (score -4):

Checkout ZStack based example [here](https://github.com/spacenation/grid)

You can select fixed columns style.

```
Grid(self.cards) { card in
    Card(title: "\(number)")
}
.gridStyle(
    FixedColumnsGridStyle(columns: 3, itemHeight: 160)
)
```

[image]