# SwiftUI Grid Index out of Range

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711736/iterate-a-grid-of-views-swiftui) of using Grid layout.

We want to display dynamically Array Items in a Grid and if the Array.count Changed an error with Index out of Range comes up and the App crashes.

How to fix this?

```
var totalrows: Int{
    let t = Double(self.cards.count) / Double(self.cols)
    return Int(round(t))
}


var cols: Int{
    let col = self.verticalSizeClass == .compact ? 4 : 2
    return col
}



func colrow (col: Int , row: Int) -> Int{
    var colrow = 0
        colrow = (row * self.cols) + col
    return colrow
}






let cards = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"]



var body: some View {

        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<self.totalrows,id:\.self) { row in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<self.cols,id:\.self) { column in
                        Text(self.cards[self.colrow(col: column, row: row)])
                    }


                }
               }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to put 2 cards in each row, if there are an odd number of cards then the last row would only contain 1 card, the index out of bounds likely occurs when you're trying to place a second card (which doesn't exist) into your last row.

Comment: yes that's right.  do you have a solution for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to avoid any indexOutOfBounds is just to check if the index is out of bounds before doing the operation...

So make this change:

```
ForEach(0..<self.cols,id:\.self) { column in
    let card = self.colrow(col: column, row: row)
    if (card < self.cards.count) {
        Text(self.cards[card])
    }
}
```

This will leave your last row potentially unfilled but it shouldn't crash

Answer (score 0):

The way you have `cols` return either 4 or 2, you will have to have an even `count` in `cards`.

I would solve this by always checking the `count` of `cards` and adding an empty item to the end if not already even.

Example:

```
//only even numbers count
var cards = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"]

if (cards.count % 2) != 0 {
    cards.add("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add custom safe subscript you'll be able to replace index out boudns array elements with anything you like using nil coalescing.

```
extension Array {
   subscript(guarded idx: Int) -> Element? {
        guard (startIndex..<endIndex).contains(idx) else { return nil }
        return self[idx]
    }
}
```

Then you could rewrite `Text` view like this to display hyphens for invalid indexes and have no crashes.

```
//...
ForEach(0..<self.cols,id:\.self) { column in
                        Text(self.cards[guarded: self.colrow(col: column, row: row)] ?? "-")
                    }
//...
```