# I don’t understand how array[row * 3+ column] creates multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

The solution to this question-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711736/iterate-a-grid-of-views-swiftui

Includes a array of cards that is iterated through like a multidimensional array, but I don't understand the [row * 3 + column] piece below.  How does that work out to be a multidimensional array?  The code looks like-

```
struct ContentView : View {
let cards = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]
var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
        ForEach(0..<cards.count/3) { row in // create number of rows
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<3) { column in // create 3 columns
                    Text(self.cards[row * 3 + column])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code is creating rows of 3 objects. it has nothing to do with a multi-dimensional array. They are just hopping * 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cards` is only a 1-dimensional array. It is just a basic array, indexed using `[]`.

In this example, a grid is created with `cards.count / 3` rows and `3` columns. The grid goes in the order of left-to-right and then down:

[image: Order]

You could think of this as the following, where green is `row` and blue is `column`:

`row × 3 + column = index in cards`

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A: `0 × 3 + 0 = 0` | B: `0 × 3 + 1 = 1` | C: `0 × 3 + 2 = 2` |
| D: `1 × 3 + 0 = 3` | E: `1 × 3 + 1 = 4` | F: `1 × 3 + 2 = 5` |
| G: `2 × 3 + 0 = 6` | H: `2 × 3 + 1 = 7` | I: `2 × 3 + 2 = 8` |
| J: `3 × 3 + 0 = 9` | K: `3 × 3 + 1 = 10` | L: `3 × 3 + 2 = 11` |

Basically for every 3 wide you are going one down. Hopefully this visual example helps you understand what that formula does.